# Why does this tooltip tell only about excerpt tag wiki editing?

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, tag-wiki, tags-page

Why does the tooltip on [the Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) tell only about excerpt tag wiki editing, despite the fact that you can edit both (short and full description)?

> [image]

Comment: Wouldn't this simply be because only the excerpts are visible on that page? The blurb below each tag is the excerpt, not the wiki, therefore it makes sense to me that you'd only mention the excerpt in the edit tooltip.